# SSIS package access Oracle DB. How do you know if you are using 32 or 64 bit Oracle driver?

Tags: oracle, ssis, driver

We have a SQL Server production box that has a 32-bit Oracle 11g driver installed.  Our current test SQL Server which has the same driver installed has been replaced by a new server that has the 64-bit 12c driver. When we test a SSIS 2012 package that pulls from Oracle and loads SQL, we will run on the new Test SQL Server using the 64-bit DTEXEC.exe utility to run the package.

**Q1:** Is it by virtue of using the 64 bit DTEXEC utility that the package will automatically seek out the 64 bit version of the driver?

I assume that in the connection string below, Provider=MSDAORA.1 refers to the MS OLE Provider for Oracle, so, I assume that I am not using the Oracle driver. I am not using a DSN.

**Q2:** Is it looking up the value of the "Data Source" property of the connectionstring, MyOracleResource.MyCompany.COM, and finding the corresponding entry in my tnsname.ora file in one of these folders based on the DTEXEC version that I use to run the package?

```
C:\Oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
C:\Oracle\product\11203_64bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
```

If so, I am surprised that the MS driver would be dependent on the tnsnames file that is created as a result of installing the Oracle client.

In the Project properties, under Property Pages->Config Properties->Debugging, there is a property, "Run64BitRunTime."

**Q3:** Am I correct to presume that when running within the IDE that this is the equivalent of selecting either a 32 or 64 bit versiobn of the DTEXE utility to run the package from the cmd line?

When I look at the properties on my Oracle connection object, I see an "ID" property with a value of {0cbfe196-1a88-4b62-8522-b34dbb37ba71}.

Q4: Is this GUID used to identify a particular driver version of the driver and therefore something that could cause of problem when testing in an environment that does not match Production?

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[MyOracleDb].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=MyOracleResource.MyCompany.COM;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Provider=MSDAORA.1;Persist Security Info=True;</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 - Yes - when you execute a package under the 64 bit version of DTEXEC, it will user the 64 bit drivers.  You can test this locally by only installing one or the other and try to run the package.  Running under the wrong version will cause the package to fail because it cannot find the drivers.

Q2 - how the server gets resolved depends on how your organization has configured your environment.  For example, where I work, there is an environment variable pushed onto each machine which points to network directories where the TNSNAMES files are stored.  You must consult your Oracle guru to understand how this works in your environment.

Q3 - The Run64BitRunTime property will cause the SSIS designer to use different versions of DtsDebugHost.exe.  Working in a similar way to DTEXEC, it will either run the 32 or 64 bit version depending on how that is set.  This is also why that property has no affect once the package is running in production - because you are using a different program to run the package entirely.

Q4 - the id property is assigned and used internally by SSIS.  If you click around, you will see that every component has an id.  So this has nothing to do with any external elements.

Comment: Q2 sounds weird to me. If you ar System or User environment variables in the Control panel under Advanced Settings (that update the registry and are accesible using %VARIABLENAME% syntax, I would say, no, we don't do that. My guess is that the installation of the 32 and 64 bit drivers makes registry changes that tell where the ROacle drivers are installed. The doubt was whether the version of DTEXEC impacted which tnsname.ora file to go with. It sound like it does. Other than the comment about ENV variables, I think I am in sync with you. ty

Comment: Your configuration for oracle is all that matters, the drivers and dtexec can't tell it where to look. If nothing is configured, it will look in the oracle_home directory. And you are correct, there are registry settings involved as well. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_HOME